# Block level elements inside of Inline elements in Slim (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to something pretty simple here. I'm using Rails 3.2.6 with Slim (slim: 1.2.2, slim-rails: 1.0.3) for templating and HTML5. HTML5 allows block level elements inside of inline elements, but I for some reason cannot get Rails/Slim to allow it and searching has lead me to nothing.

If I do:

```
a.my_container href="#"
    div.inner_portion
        h2 Heading
        h4 Subheading
```

It will render as:

```
<a class="my_container" href="#"></a>
<div class="inner_portion">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <h4>Subheading</h4>
</div>
```

I've also attempted to escape the surrounding anchor html, as well as link_to ... do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Rails nor Slim - as opposed to the browser - care about the nesting of your block and inline elements. Slim will nest everything exactly as you tell it to, no matter whether it is valid HTML or not.

Therefore I assume that you somehow got your indentation wrong, you should check that.